# WPF ZoomControl and Adorners

Tags: wpf, image, coordinates, zooming

This my first post on stack overflow, I hope I get it right. I am using the ZoomControl from WPF Extensions to display an image with pan and zoom support:

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="1" x:Name="canvas">            
     <Controls:ZoomControl  x:Name="zoomControl">  
        <Canvas x:Name="canvas">     
             <Image x:Name="imageControl" Stretch="None" />
        </Canvas> 
     </Controls:ZoomControl>
</DockPanel>
```

When the user selects an image with a bowse dialog, I load that image like so:

```
  bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fileName));
  this.imageControul.Source = bmp;
```

I would like to added rectangles\adorners to specific locations (pixel coordinates) on the image the user loaded based on some image processing.

```
var r = new Rectangle();
 r.StrokeThickness = 5;
 r.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
 r.Fill = Brushes.Transparent;
 r.Width = width;
 r.Height = height;

 Canvas.SetLeft(r, y);
 Canvas.SetTop(r, x);

 canvas.Children.Add(r);
```

However, the rectangles are not placed in the expected locations? Wrong scale and location.

Thanks,

John

Comment: What is the "specific location" for the rectangle? Should the rectangle simply be a border for the entire image?

Answer (score 0):

I expect the problem is that your Canvas is expanding to fill the space rather than being locked to the rectangle. Have a look with a tool like Snoop and see what the bounding boxes of the two are.

You might be able to fix it with Horizontal and VercticalAlignment on the canvas, set them to anything other than Stretch.

If that doesn't work restructure it like this

```
<ZoomBox>
  <Grid>
     <Image/>
     <Canvas/>
  </Grid>
</ZoomBox>
```

So the Image and the canvas are grouped by the parent Grid which is being transformed.